# Where to get help for Amazon Web Services API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working with Amazon's Product Advertising API and need some help on a few issues. The questions I have posted on SO and Amazon developer forums have gone unanswered. Where can I find help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your best bet is going to be to pay amazon for support: http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/

My guess is that there aren't many people using that API hence the problem getting regular programmers to help you.  This is evidenced by a notice on the main AWS page (https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) about a number of discontinued API operations and responses due to low usage.

"low usage" in this scenario is usually marketing speak meaning "no one except that one guy in Minnesota".

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.